# when do we consider a worker thread as free in Executor Service

Tags: java, multithreading, executorservice

I am having a conceptual problem in understanding the working of fixedthreadpool of executor service.
Suppose I have a fixed pool thread of n threads and I am submitting several tasks to this service. Now if a worker is available, it executes the submitted task and other submitted tasks wait in the queue until a worker is free.
My question is, when do we consider a worker as a free worker thread ?
Do we consider a worker thread free as soon as it starts submitted task irrespective of task's completion or we consider a worker thread busy as long as submitted task is in progress.
Let's say we have a worker thread W1 in the pool and a Task Op1 is submitted to the executor.
W1 starts Op1 at time T1 and after some time Op1 finished its execution at time T3. Here T3 > T1
Now do we consider W1 as free as soon as it starts Op1 at time T1 or it is considered busy and will be free at time T3.

Thanks in advance !!

Comment: "Do we consider a worker thread free as soon as it starts submitted task" why would we define it that way?

Comment: A worker thread is considered to be 'free' when it is capable of doing work (i.e. it is currently not executing a task).

Comment: All worker threads are born free! ;-)

Comment: One more point, in case of ScheduledExecutorService a task runs repeatedly(as per its defined frequency). Any free worker can pick this scheduled task in any iteration. Isn't it ?

Answer (score 2):

Well, it's very simple... let's get started.

1. Thread Pool executes tasks. Tasks that are submitted to it are stored in the queue.
2. A task implements the `runnable` interface, thus it has a run method that does not take any arguments and return void. This method acts as an entry point or the method that is called by the "thread that would be executing you task" in the thread pool.
3. Now, back to the thread pool:
   a. Thread pool compromises of a internal queue could be `ArrayBlockingQueue`/`LinkedBlockingQueue`, etc... The main point is: it is always a queue.
   b. A group of threads that continuously poll this queue.

The thread that executes your task looks like this some what

> ```
> void run() {
>     while (true) {
>         //Get the task from the thread pool internal queue (1)      
>         //Call the run method of the task. 
>         //If the execution of the task throws a Runtime exception - catch it and display it. (2)
>     }
>  }
> ```

So, as u can see, the worker will only be free if there are no task in the queue. The worker would either be polling the queue for task (1) or executing the task (2).

Answer (score 2):

A worker thread is free when it is `takes`ing off the queue.  Any given worker thread take's off the queue when it no longer is running the task. So it would look something like

```
private final BlockingQueue<Runnable> workQueue;

class WorkerThread {
   public void run(){
      while(true){
        Runnable r = workQueue.take(); // worker thread is 'free'
        r.run(); // worker thread is busy
      }
   }
}
```

So to answer your question, a particular worker thread is free when it is not executing a task submitted to the service.

Comment: Okay.. it means a worker is busy from the time it takes the task from queue till the time taken by the task to complete its run method.. am I getting it right ?

Comment: Yes, thats right.  The caveat is if there is no elements in the queue then it will wait for one to exist, your snippet of 'the time it takes the task from queue' can be left off.  

So it's more correct to say - the thread is busy from the time after it takes a task off the queue to completion of the run method.

Comment: One more question, in case of ScheduledExecutorService a task runs repeatedly(as per its defined frequency). Any free worker can pick this scheduled task in any iteration. Isn't it ? I mean to say once a task is scheduled for its first iteration, its future iterations can be serviced by any free worker at that instance of time?